# Remove command not working

Tags: 12.04, trash, rm

rm command not working.when i type command rm file name it giving me error

```
No command 'trash' found, did you mean:
Command 'crash' from package 'crash' (main)
Command 'ktrash' from package 'kde-runtime' (main)
trash: command not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say the rm command isn't working but your output it relating to the trash command.

Try typing

```
    rm --help
```

Please confirm the directory /bin/rm exists.

Answer (score 2):

From the error above, it looks like you're typing `trash` instead of `rm`.  Trash does the same as `rm`, but it has to be installed first.  To install it, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install trash-cli
```

once installed, you can type trash , to delete the file, or trash --help for help on using the command.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **"trash-put"** command istead.

My trash-cli version is 0.11.3 and 
there is no "trash" command in my /usr/bin.
There are commands "trash-put", "trash-list", "trash-empty" and
"restore-trash".

To use the short word "trash" instead of "trash-put"
i added an alias to my ~/.bashrc file like this:
`alias trash='trash-put'`

And then i typed

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

to reload the new ~/.bashrc version.

Answer (score 0):

First check that `rm` exists in your bin folder.

If it does, but you get this message, you may have an alias. Type `alias` into your terminal to see if you have something like `alias rm='trash -v'`. You can remove this alias for your current terminal session by typing `unalias rm`. If you want to completely remove this alias you may need to check your configuration file (e.g. `.bashrc` or whatever you use) and change it there.